# If/Else statement for chart

Tags: vb.net, excel, mschart

So, I've been stuck in this problem for so many days now. I'm trying to loop the system.array from the data in Excel. I use the if statement that read if the data value from the excel is numeric or not. After that I put elseif statement that change the chart marker style to none if the value is equal to zero. However, no matter what kind of methods that I try, the markers still show on the chart. Here's my code:

```
Dim A_GTRng As Excel.Range
Dim A_GTArry As System.Array

'Set the range
A_GTRng = excelWS.Range("I2", excelWS.Range("I2").End(Excel.XlDirection.xlDown))

'Read in the values of a range of cells
A_GTArry = CType(A_GTRng.Value, System.Array)

'Looping through the A_GTArry
    For x As Integer = 1 To A_GTArry.GetUpperBound(0)
        For y As Integer = 1 To A_GTArry.GetUpperBound(1)
            Dim A_GT As Object = A_GTArry(x, y)
            If IsNumeric(y).Equals(0) Then
                'Chart1.Series("A_GT").MarkerSize = 0
                'Chart1.Series("A_GT").MarkerColor = Color.Transparent
                Chart1.Series("A_GT").MarkerStyle = MarkerStyle.None
            ElseIf IsNumeric(y) Then
                'Chart1.Series("A_GT").Points.Dispose()
                Chart1.Series("A_GT").Points.AddY(A_GT)
                Chart1.Series("A_GT").MarkerStyle = MarkerStyle.Diamond
                Chart1.Series("A_GT").MarkerColor = Color.Red
                Chart1.Series("A_GT").MarkerSize = 7
            End If
        Next y
    Next x
```

Result from the program above: 
[image]
Can anyone check if I make some mistake somewhere? I try to solve this problem since the past few days, but did got the result that I want. My brain pretty much fried now. I really need help to solve this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Since y is an Integer by definition in your For loop it will always be numeric.

Therefore this statement will never succeed:

```
If IsNumeric(y).Equals(0) Then
```

What exactly are you trying to do? Seems like you've gotten a little bit off course.

Z

Comment: If you see my chart, I want the program to show the one that over the red line. I want to get rid the points on the zero, but no success with it. How can I make all the red dots on the zero disappear?